# What is the expected way of handling abstract domain classes as command objects or command object properties in Grails?

Tags: grails, data-binding, grails-orm, command-objects

Grails supports domain classes as properties of command objects out of the box. I can use a domain class `Stuff` with a command `StuffCommand`, but not if `Stuff` is an abstract class.

**Stuff.groovy**

```
abstract class Stuff{
}
```

**StuffCommand.groovy**

```
class StuffCommand{
    Stuff stuff
}
```

**ExampleController.groovy**

```
class ExampleController{
    def doStuffWithStuff(StuffCommand stuffCmd){
        render stuffCmd.stuff ? stuffCmd.stuff as JSON : ''
    }
}
```

Then, the request `http://server:port/ctx/example/doStuffWithStuff?stuff=123` will not get the record #123 out of the `stuff` table from my database. I love the concise nature of that approach. The query on the database either does not take place or fails silently.

The following workaround helps a little, though:

Create a class that converts `ValueConverter` for the abstract comain class. The class name must end with `ValueConverter`, other than that you can name it at will, for instance `IdStringToStuffValueConverter`.

**IdStringToStuffValueConverter**

```
import org.grails.databinding.converters.ValueConverter

class IdStringToStuffValueConverter implements ValueConverter{
    @Override
    boolean canConvert(Object value) {
        value instanceof String || value instanceof Integer || value instanceof Long
    }

    @Override
    Object convert(Object value) {
        return Stuff.get(value.toLong())
    }

    @Override
    Class<?> getTargetType() {
        return Stuff
    }
}
```

Now I can fire above request and the controller will hit the database again during data binding. But the following does still not work as expected:

ExampleController.groovy

```
class ExampleController{
    def doStuffWithStuff(Stuff stuff){
        render stuff ? stuff as JSON : ''
    }
}
```

During this action no database queries take place, hence the workaround does not cover this case. How can I use abstract domain classes as command objects?

Comment: You should re-work your question to show the non-working bits, otherwise there may not be enough information to get a proper answer.

Comment: Done, maybe it is more clear now. I have also edited the question name.